# Let $X_1, . . . , X_9$ be a random sample from $N(μ, 4)$

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1, . . . , X_9$ be a random sample from $N(μ, 4)$ with $μ$ unknown and let $\overline{X}_9$ be the sample mean. Then $3\frac{\overline{X}_9-\mu}{4}$ has distribution $N(0, 1/4)$.

Can someone explain me why this statement is true, why the distribution is $N(0, 1/4)$? I tried to prove it with CLT but I can't arrive to this distribution.

Comment: You don't need CLT, you're working with normal distributions for which [there are simple theorems about addition and scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_normal_deviates).

Comment: You probably mean $\overline{X}$ instead of $\overline{X}_9$ for the sample mean? For your question: What properties does a random sample have?

Comment: @user190080 Some texts, particularly statistical ones, use $\bar{X}_n$ to emphasize the sample size $n$.

Comment: @user190080 they put $\overline{X}_9$ but I think that they consider the same thing. The random sample belong to a normal distribution.

Comment: @LukeMarci So they are *independent* and identically distributed (following the given normal one). Do you know how to calculate the distribution now?

Comment: Honestly no :( sorry